# The Best Python Framework For Data Science

Tags: python, machine-learning, frameworks, data-science

My goal is to land a job in Data Science and I would like to ask the people who already work in this field and who can give me advise which Python Framework (**Flask** or **Django**) should I master / focus on?

My plan is to create machine learning projects and deploy them to a server, and present them as my experience since I don't have any actual work experience in this field. But I don't want to make a mistake spending hours and hours mastering framework that no one use and then learn again.

Thank You.

Comment: To make a long story short, both of them are frequently used in many projects of all size. There isn't one that is inherently better than the other, they both allow to have the job done with their own advantages and disadvantages. For instance (from my personal experience),  flask is easier to learn, but you will have a better time searching help on django if you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both are good options.

Flask for small scope.

Django is complete, has feature for almost everything out of the box.

You might also include in your stack: pandas, spark, tensor flow, Apache Bean, Google Data Flow, and other related stuff.

Start doing small projects from the courses and tutorials to begin a portfolio, always go for the official documentation to tie up things.

Answer (score 1):

The most important is one Python. Getting really good with Python is the most important pre-requisite.

Then learn data Science Python libraries, first NumPy, and then Pandas.

After that move on to advanced tools like TensorFlow, or the programming language R.

One of the best places to learn more about these technologies, take free courses on freecodecamp.org, first do the course on Python computing, then TensorFlow, both of these are great.